# LoadRunner RTE Protocal.The main scenrio is total we have 1000 set of data

Tags: performance, rte

The main scenrio is total we have 1000 set of data...Total data should consume in  60 min..But The high priority with in 10 min 500 data should consume,rest 50 min remaining 500 data should consume..How can we handle this,can anyone give me solution or ideas in this..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Schedule two groups with different numbers of users and pacing.  Time your first group to handle your 500 consumption in 10 minutes and your second group to fire at the conclusion of your first group.

This is not a protocol specific problem, but one related to load test design, scheduling and pacing.

Comment: Thanq James .In runtime settings i need to set the blocks right ???How can i set the time...in 10 min total 500 set  of how it will consume..Can u plz expina in breifly

Comment: This is basic load modeling.  This is a foundation skill.  Please refer to your instructor/mentor for setting a model on how to hit a given number of business transactions within a defined period of time with a fixed number of users.