# How to insert Rendezvous function in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

How to insert Rendezvous function in laodrunner..In actionpart how can i set that Can anyone please help me...is this work for this requriment.
first 2 hrs 1000 set of data should comsume...Nxt 10 min 2000 set of should consume,Nxt 1 hr 50 min rest 1000 data need to consumeeeee

Comment: Moderator, this is essentially the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322606/loadrunner-rte-protocal-the-main-scenrio-is-total-we-have-1000-set-of-data

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lr_rendezvous` command in the script, which creates a rendezvous point in the Vuser script, where you want all users to "meet up" before executing the next set of commands.

For example:

```
lr_rendezvous("consume");

(run the command)
```

This will cause all virtual users ("VUsers") to stop at the rendezvous point, until all other users have reached it, and only then run.

Comment: Thanq so much koby....But in Action part where should i insert this  lr_rendezvous("consume");

Comment: I voted the answer up as technically correct, but this user really has no idea why they are asking for rendezvous which is completely out of context for the desirement so posted in the original note.

Comment: Hi james i posted one requirment right  stackoverflow.com/questions/43322606/… –  .That got passed..I have written the script.Its working succesfully...Thought of sharing ..Big success..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need rendezvous to meet your requirement.   In fact, this would likely be an incorrect use of this functionality.  As noted in other forums where this exact question has been asked, this is an issue of scheduling.   You have different groups with different schedules for execution>

Group 1 schedule 1.  Runs for two hours.  Assuming one unique set of data for each iteration and assuming 100 users, then you have each user consuming 10 sets of data.  Over a two hour period this iteration pacing is once every 720 seconds per user.  How is that arrived at?  2 hours = 7200 seconds.   Your user has to go through 10 iterations in the two hours to use their data.  7200/10 = 720 seconds.   This is your median value, setting +/- 20% should achieve some degree of natural behavior while still hitting the midpoint for large enough sample sets.

You can cary this out for the next group, which runs after the first one completes for 10 minutes.  100 users, 2000 sets of data yields 20 iterations in 10 minutes.  10 minutes=600 seconds.  600/20 = 30 seconds of iteration pacing.   If you alter the users, the transactions, etc... then your pacing interval changes to hit your requirement.

If you want to guarantee uniqueness across all of your users across multiple groups on multiple load generators then you should consider feeding your scripts from a queue instead of a local data file.   The virtual table server ships with LoadRunner.  I prefer to use the HTTP interface of RabbitMQ.

**This is basic load modeling.** This is a foundation level skill, before you pick up any performance testing tool.  You should not be allowed to use any performance testing tool without a solid foundation of these concepts.  Assuming you are new to the field, hence your question and desire to use rendezvous (which will cause more issues here than you care to know about), **your management owes you both training and a mentor for a period of time if they are interested in your success.**  Social promotion into this field does not work there are foundation skills you need to master before constructing a test.

Next, as to your requirement.  It is odd, very odd.  It seems as if someone with a functional testing background has decided that they want you to engage in what is termed "a day in a day," attempting to model the ebbs and flows of data through the system observed in a particular time period.  You can get this at the database layer with some dbreplay features on particular platforms, but performance testing tools are not designed for this.  You will fall short, and guaranteed to do so as a newcomer to the field.   You should also be asking what question are you trying to answer and what is the value of the answer.  There is most certainly a shorter path.

Comment: Hello james..Thanq so much for your response...Iam not new to this loadrunner.Iam experienced.Iam new to this kind of requirment..This is not odd requirment actually,In real scenrio they are facing same thing,So they want to test it,Planning to do in Blocks may be that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert lr_rendezvous function before the main transaction's execution where you are expecting to have the maximum user load.
For ex. lr_rendezvous("Login");
lr_start_transaction("Login");
This way, all the users will wait until ramp up before Login transaction.
Hope this helps.

Regards.